# Get foreign serialized ReadOnlyField on Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Currently I have a serializer file like so:

```
class BotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Bot
        fields = ['id', 'bot_name', 'comment', 'bot_activities']
        depth = 1


class BotActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bot_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='bot.bot_name', read_only=True)
    started_date_activity = serializers.DateTimeField(source='started_at', format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", required=False, read_only=True)
    finished_date_activity = serializers.DateTimeField(source='finished_at', format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", required=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BotActivity
        fields = ['started_at', 'started_date_activity', 'finished_at', 'finished_date_activity', 'bot', 'bot_name', 'bot_activity_status']
```

When I call the Bot seriliazer I get:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "bot_name": "HTTP header checker",
    "comment": "testtest",
    "bot_activities": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "started_at": "2020-11-04T15:47:26.168212Z",
            "finished_at": null,
            "bot_activity_status": "In Progress",
            "bot": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

But I need to also get the started_date_activity and finished_date_activity fields.
What to do to get their value too?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution :

```
class BotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bot_activities = BotActivitySerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
```